# Is a time complexity of O(nlogn) + O(n) just O(nlogn)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Let's say I have an array of length `n` and I sorted through it using a sorting algorithm with time `nlogn`. After getting this sorted array, I iterate through it to find any repeating elements with linear time. My understanding is that since the operations happened separately, this would be time `O(nlogn) + O(n)` and not `O(nlogn+n)`. If that's the case, would `nlogn` over take the linear time complexity making the final time complexity `O(nlogn)`?

Comment: Your intuition is correct but your phrasing is not quite precise.  I would recommend reading up on the definition of Big O time complexity, and once you have a grasp of the basic ideas things will be more clear to you.

Comment: `O(m) + O(n) = O(max(m, n))`

Comment: @0x499602D2 not quite, if m and n are independent of each other (eg path finding on V nodes and E edges) then O(m) + O(n) = O(m+n)

Comment: @Budd You're right. So would `O(f(n)) + O(g(n)) = O(max(f(n), g(n)))` be more precise?

Comment: for large n the complexity will be `O(nlogn)`

Answer (score 4):

yes, as log(n) > 1 for large n, so O(nlog(n)) is a superset of O(n)

Answer (score 3):

> O(nlogn) + O(n) and not O(nlogn+n)

There is no such thing; *O*(*n* log *n*) + *O*(*n*) and *O*(*n* log *n* + *n*) are equal, and both are equal to *O*(*n* log *n*). So it's not possible for a function to be in one and not the other.